# RSpec: All tests failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rspec2, railstutorial.org

I am following the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl. My tests were all passing till I migrated the database and added the last 2 test. Something got messed up since all the tests are failing now even if I remove the last 2 tests. I am not sure if I made some mistake with the migrate or something else.

This is what I used:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
$ bundle exec rake db:test:prepare
$ bundle exec rspec spec/
```

Here's the user_spec file which fails completely:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  before do
   @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar") 
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
  before { @user.name = " " }
  it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " "}
    it { should_not be_valid }

  end

  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a"*51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
        addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo. foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar_baz.com]
         addresses.each do |invalid_address|
            @user.email = invalid_address
            @user.should_not be_valid 
        end
    end
  end

    describe "when email format is valid" do
        it "should be valid" do
            addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
                addresses.each do |valid_address|
                    @user.email = valid_address
                    @user.should be_valid
                end
            end
        end

    describe "when email address is already taken" do
        before do
            user_with_same_email = @user.dup
            user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
            user_with_same_email.save
        end

        it { should_not be_valid }
    end


    describe "when password is not present" do
      before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end 

    describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
      before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    describe "when password confirmation is nil" do
      before { @user.password_confirmation = nil }
      it { should_not be_valid }
    end
end
```

And here is the migration file:

```
class AddPassswordDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :password_digest, :string
  end
end
```

EDIT2 - I just removed `password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar"` from the first line of the spec and now I only get 5 errors (which is right as those related to password should fail)

EDIT1 - Here are the failing tests

```
Running all specs
Running tests with args ["--drb", "-f", "progress", "-r", "/home/niranjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/guard-rspec-1.2.1/lib/guard/rspec/formatters/notification_rspec.rb", "-f", "Guard::RSpec::Formatter::NotificationRSpec", "--out", "/dev/null", "--failure-exit-code", "2", "spec"]...
..FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.........

Failures:

  1) User 
     Failure/Error: @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: password
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:16:in `new'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User 
     Failure/Error: @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: password
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:16:in `new'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User 
     Failure/Error: @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: password
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:16:in `new'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) User 
     Failure/Error: @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
     ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError:
       unknown attribute: password
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:16:in `new'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

.... and so on

Comment: How exactly does it fail? Paste an excerpt of the error messages you are receiving.

Comment: @RenatoZannon Please look at my latest edit, The problem goes away by removing the `password` and `password_confirmation`. But why does everything fail when I put them back?

Comment: It actually isn't a problem, the failures are expected, take a look at my response. Cool name, by the way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the book:

> Putting everything together gives the (failing) tests in Listing 6.28. We’ll get them to pass in Section 6.3.4.

The tests *should* be failing. They will pass as soon as the password implementation is done, later on the tutorial.

---

Now, to explain *why* they are failing:

On the line where you create the user (your `before` block), you are passing the `password` attribute to the constructor, but that attribute doesn't exist yet, so your model complains with the errors you are seeing. On the tutorial this attribute is created a little later.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot! I tried to run the tests before reading ahead. Appreciate it